# How render components after fetching data

Tags: reactjs

I have a container called "Recetas" (Receipes) which has inside a component called "Showcase". The idea is that the user can create a request in "Recetas" and when the data is fetched, the container will re-render and "Showcase" will update with the new data.

I'm saving the request in the state of "Recetas" and passing the data to "Showcase" with props.

The problem is that the render is being execute before I receive the new data. So I'm always showing "old" data. Is there any way I can put on hold the render until I've received the data? Or how can I solve it?

```
class Recetas extends Component {
state = {
    loading: false,
    data: [],
    maxResult: 12,
    minResult: 0,
    query: 'burger',
    appId: 'xxxxxx',
    appKey: 'xxxxx'
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
}

async fetchData() {
    this.setState({loading: true});
    console.log('fetching ...');
    try {
        const request = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${this.state.query}&app_id=${this.state.appId}&app_key=${this.state.appKey}&from=${this.state.minResult}&to=${this.state.maxResult}`;
        console.log('request: ', request);
        const result = await axios(request);
        this.setState({ data: result.data.hits, loading: false });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

queryHandler = value => {
    this.setState({
        query: value
    });
    this.fetchData();
}

render() {

    return (

        <div className={classes.Recetas}>
            {console.log('actualState: ', this.state)}
            <SearchInput 
                query={this.state.query} 
                queryHandler={(value) => this.queryHandler(value)}/>

            <Showcase 
                data={this.state.data}
                loading={this.state.loading}/>

        </div>
    ); 
}
```

Showcase component

```
const showcase = props => {

const spinner = <Spinner />;
const recetas = props.data.map((elem, index) => {
    return <Receta key={index} title={elem.recipe.label} url={elem.recipe.image} />
});

console.log('[Showcase] props.data: ', props.data);
return (

    <div className={classes.Showcase}>
        {props.loading ? spinner : recetas}
    </div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve it adding a setTimeout function which execute the fetch 500 ms after updating the state in 'queryhandler' method.

Comment: I know, what would you do?

Answer (score 0):

In case the Function Component not watch the `props` change. You should move the spinner to the container component.

```
Recetas.js

render() {
  ...
  const {loading, data} = this.state
  return (
    ...
    <div className={classes.Recetas}>
        {loading ? < Spinner /> : <Showcase data={data} />}
    </div>
  ); 
}    

//////////////
ShowCase.js

const showcase = props => (
  <div className={classes.Showcase}>
  {
    props.data.map(({recipe: {label, imgage}}, index) => <Receta key={index} title={label} url={image} />)
  }                            
  </div>
)
```

And using [Destructuring_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for shorter code.